# MongoDB covered query needs to fetch and examine documents when exists operator is used

Tags: index, mongodb

I need to execute following query on mongo db:

```
db.testCollection.find({ dataType: { $exists: true } }, { _id: 0, date: 1 })
   .sort({ date: -1 })
   .limit(1)
```

so basically only I need to do is to find newest date from documents that have `dataType` field.
I have ~20 milion documents in that collection and this query last something like 4-5 minutes.
I tried to cover all query needs by index, so I created index like this:

```
db.testCollection.ensureIndex(
   { dataType: 1, date: -1 }, 
   { partialFilterExpression: { dataType: { $exists: true } } }
)
```

As far as I know, this index contains all data the query needs:

- information that all documents in this index contains `dataType` field exists
- `date` field value needed to retreived it from query
- `date` field value needed to sort operation

Unfortunately, mongo still have `FETCH` stage in query plan to check if `dataType` filed exists:

```
"winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
            "transformBy" : {
                "_id" : 0,
                "date" : 1
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "date" : -1
                },
                "limitAmount" : 1,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "dataType" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "dataType" : 1,
                                "date" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "dataType_1_date_-1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "dataType" : [ ],
                                "date" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : true,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "dataType" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "date" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So my question is why mongo still needs to fetch document from collections?

EDIT: When I changed `$exists` operator to `$ne: null` it doesn't need to execute `FETCH` stage.

Answer (score 0):

I see similar results when tried on MongoDB v4.2.8 - using the posted info.

In general, the `$exists` in a query filter uses the index on that field. For example, if there is a field `fld1` and you run a query with a filter `{ fld1: {$exists: true}}`, the query uses the index.

In the query plan output, the in-memory sort ("stage" : "SORT") is because - for a compound index the filter must be an *equality* condition on the index prefix field (`dataType`) and then only the index will be used in a sort operation using the `date` field. The FETCH is for the SORT operation to happen in the memory (i.e., the index is not being used). So, the query is not covered.

For example, a query like this will use the index (and it will be covered):

```
db.test.find({ dataType: "a" }, { date: 1, _id: 0 }).sort({ date: -1 })
```

It is important to note that the query filter `{ dataType: "a" }` uses an *equality* condition - and, `{dataType: {$exists: true}}` does not.

See [Sort and Non-prefix Subset of an Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/index.html#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index)

Answer (score 0):

The index specification `{ dataType: 1, date: -1 }` means the index entries will be sorted first by `dataType` and then by `date`.

That does not match the sort requested by the query: `{ date: -1 }`.

If you were to build the index like the following, the query execution could avoid using an in-memory sort, and examine only 1 document, which should give better performance.

```
db.testCollection.ensureIndex(
   { date: -1 }, 
   { partialFilterExpression: { dataType: { $exists: true } } }
)
```